# PublishProcessor in RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

I have a `PublishProcessor` which emits values continuously. And I have subscribed the `PublishProcessor` with two subscribers which observe on two different thread. While the first subscriber continuously receives the data in `onNext(T)`, the second subscriber throws error `Error: Could not emit value due to lack of requests` after receiving few calls to `onNext(T)`

Below is my implementation

```
PublishProcessor<byte[]> publishProcessor = PublishProcessor.create()
dataFlowable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(publishProcessor);
```

Subscriber1

```
publishProcessor.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<byte[]>() {
      @Override public void onNext(byte[] bytes) {
        //Log.i("Sub1 ", "Data received");
      }

      @Override public void onError(Throwable t) {

      }

      @Override public void onComplete() {
        Log.i("Record ", "complete");
      }
    })
```

Subscriber2

```
publishProcessor.observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<byte[]>() {
      @Override public void onNext(byte[] moreData) {
          Log.i("Sub2 ", "Data received");
      }

      @Override public void onError(Throwable t) {
        Log.i("Sub2 ", t.getMessage() + " ");   // error received after few call to onNext()
      }

      @Override public void onComplete() {
        Log.i("Sub2 ", "complete");
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a `MissingBackpressureException`. It is occurring because the publisher is producing faster than the subscribers can consume. `PublishProcessor` does not apply backpressure from its downstream subscribers to its upstream sources.

What is `dataFlowable`? Why not subscribe to it directly?

Comment: My requirement is to subscribe the `dataFlowable` with more than one subscriber which I can use directly. So I'm using PublishProcessor here.

Comment: @arjun If `dataFlowable` is a hot source then you can add multiple subscribers to it directly. If it is a cold source then you can add your subscriptions to one `.publish() -> ConnectedFlowable`.